# LINQ Database View Unwanted Caching Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am utilizing Devexpress Gridview and I am having a caching problem.

I have developed a page like here: http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/SimpleCustomBinding

It is working as it is supposed to be. However, if I update a column value in the database (Mssql), Gridview does not change the value.

Searched the web and found EnableRowsCache must be false but I could not implemented it since I think this property is available for different kind (or version) of Gridview and We have been using MVC extensions.

Does anybody know how to disable cache and make it show the "fresh" data?

**------ UPDATE ------**

After a lot of digging and searching, it is clear now that the caching is not due to devexpress, but it is the result of linq to sql. It is a property of linq that it caches the results of view and does not show the updated value.

Comment: It seems more interesting now, As far as i have experimented, if the data source in database is a table, gridview works as expected, shows the updated value in grid. However, if the datasource is a view in database, gridview shows the older value after update. (But view shows the updated value if we look to the database. ) it is interesting, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a major headheache to us and now I have come up with a conclusion with my colleague.

**PROBLEM**

First of all, suppose that you have a view in your db, name: ViewBook

```
ViewBook
Id | Title | Author
```

And you write the following query:

```
(from VB in Connection.ViewBook
select VB).ToList();
```

As a result you will get a list of rows.

Then, if you update a row in your db, this query will not show the fresh data, still returns the old data.

**SOLUTION**

In order to solve this, first define an object:

```
public class ViewBookObject : ViewBook
{
  //this object will have all the properties of ViewBook.
}
```

then in the query:

```
(from VB in Connection.ViewBook
select new ViewBookObject {
  Id = VB.Id,
  Title = VB.Title,
  Author = VB.Author
}).ToList();
```

This query will always show the fresh data.

**CONCLUSION**

I have written this solution to here for people who have similar problem to this situation.

I hope this helps everyone.